# Learning smali and Dalvik and Android Run Time

Tags: android, dalvik, smali, art-runtime

we all know that google is shifting from Dalvik to ART ( 4.4.2 has even experimental support too) for obvious reason, A very basic question is arising in my mind after i recently started working on mdifying the generated smali files for some purpose. Here is my question:

After expanding any apk file we see dalvik executable and various smali file containing dalvik opcodes and other related things. So i was surprised if this structure inside the apk file will be containing the similar things going forward once Google forces to use ART i.e. I am not clear if modifying the smali file will be valid once ART takes over.

This may be very basic question for many but is my first question in this forum so please excuse me for my limited knowledge on this topic.

Comment: ART is still an engine for accomplishing the execution of architecture-agnostic Dalvik code on a specific device; it just uses a different strategy for when/how to convert Dalvik instructions to native ones.

Comment: Chris Stratton's comment has the answer to this question +1